# Python nest list performance choice

Tags: python, list

I am trying to understand if there is an advantage in space/time/programming to storing data from a signal processing system as nested list in either :

1. `data[channel][sample]`
2. `data[sample][channel]`

I can code processing for both - thou I personally find 1) easy to write and index to then 2).
However, 2) is the more common was my local group programs in and stores the data (either in excel/csv or from the data gathering systems).   While it is easy to transpose

```
dataA = map(list, zip(*dataB))
```

I was wondering if there are any storage or performance - or even - module compatibility issues with 1 over 2?

with 1) I can loop like this

```
for R in dataA :
   for C in R :
       process_channel(C)

matplotlib.loglog(dataA[0], dataA[i])
```

where `dataA[0]` is time or frequency and i is some other channel to plot

with 2)

```
for R in dataB :
    for C in R
        process_sample(C)

matplotlib.loglog([j[0] for j in dataB],[k[i] for k in dataB])
```

This looks worse in programming style.  Maybe I am missing a list method of making this easier?  I have also developed code to used dicts ... but this really breaks with general use.  So I am less inclined to continue to use dicts.  Although the dict storage is

```
dataC = list(['f':0.1,'chnl1':100.0],['f':0.2,'chnl1':110.0])
```

or some such. It seems that to be better integrated option 2 is better.  However, I am trying to understand how better to code when using option 2) when you wish to process over channels then samples?   Just transpose the matrix first and then do the work in option 1) space and transpose back the results:

```
dataA = smoothing(dataA, smooth_factor)

def smoothing(d, s) :
    td = numpy.transpose(d)
    td = map(list, zip(*d))
    nd=[]
    for row in td :
       col = []
       for i in xrange(0,len(row)-step,step) :
           col.append(sum(row[i:i+step]/step)
       nd.append(col)
    nd = numpy.transpose(nd)
    return nd
```

while this construction works - transposing back and forth all the time looks - um - inefficient.

Comment: Which of the two options is more efficient depends on how you access the arrays/loop over them. If `sample` is the inner loop, go for 1. otherwise for 2. . If there is another question here, please clarify.

Comment: In terms of saving programming time, particularly debugging time, follow the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and store the data in the shape that will be least surprising to everyone working with this data.  That will probably be (2) above.